# I have a button that changes colors when clicked, but I need it to include the tints of green

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, button, colors

This set of code cycles between black (#000000) and pure green (#00ff00). I need to also include tints of green up through white, however. So, once the button is clicked enough times and pure green (#00ff00) is displayed, What do I need to do to have it continue cycling up through the tints until white (#ffffff) is displayed?

```
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click',()=>{
div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color)+10;
var c = div.dataset.color%256;
div.style.background = 'rgb(0,'+c+',0)';
})

#myDiv {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #000000;
}

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

For example, Tints of Green include #19ff19, #32ff32, #4cff4c, #66ff66, #7fff7f, #99ff99, #b2ffb2, #ccffcc, #e5ffe5, etc. All of which are not included in the colors presented by the original code (pasted above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you 'max out' green, you can step up white tone by increasing red and blue equally. Think of it as having 256 * 2 shades to go through: 256 shades from black to green and 256 shades from green to white:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click',() => {

  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color) + 10;

  var c = div.dataset.color % 512;
  var rb = c - 256 > 0 ? c - 256 : 0; // gets 'overage' of values past 256;

  div.style.background = `rgb(${rb},${c},${rb})`;
});

#myDiv {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #000000;
}

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

In this example, we are stepping up green values by ten each click, and then for each click over 256 we add ten to both red and blue, which should keep the same increment between color shades.

Since we need to basically count to 256 twice, we can modulo `div.dataset.color` (green) by 512. This means the green value could get higher than 256; we could do some logic to fix this, but browsers will still just use the max color value of 256 if anything greater is put in. No need to fix it.

This example will also automatically cycle back to black after white is attained. To prevent going back to black, you could do some logic to stop counting after 512.

*note: I saw you were using ES6 fat arrows so I updated the rgb string to string literal syntax :)*